# How to recursively remove all files in a directory except specific file type and folder?

Tags: rm

Assume I have a directory which contains:

```
.\Folder\Folder1\exe\a.exe
.\Folder\Folder1\dll\b.dll
.\Folder\Folder1\txt\c.txt
.\Folder\Folder2\exe\a.exe
.\Folder\Folder2\dll\b.dll
.\Folder\Folder2\txt\c.txt
.
.
.
```

Now I want to recursively remove from .\Folder\ except all *.txt, such that:

```
.\Folder\Folder1\exe\
.\Folder\Folder1\dll\
.\Folder\Folder1\txt\c.txt
.\Folder\Folder2\exe\
.\Folder\Folder2\dll\
.\Folder\Folder2\txt\c.txt
.
.
.
```

Could anyone please suggest the command for using rm to do the job? Thanks!

### I tried:

```
cd .\Folder
shopt -s extglob
```

### rm -rf !("*.txt")

but it delete all files and directory inside .\Folder

Answer (score 1):

All i think the righ command is :

```
rm -vrf ./Folder/Folder*/*/!(*.txt)
```

Comment: if just delete file txt just use: rm -rf ./Folder/Folder*/*/!("*.txt")

Comment: sry the answer is : rm -vrf ./Folder/Folder*/*/!(*.txt) . I add -v option to know what i delete. The different is character "

Comment: it returns: zsh: no matches found: ./Folder/Folder*/*/!(*.txt) so failed. it should be "find .\/Folder -type f ! -name "*.txt" -exec rm -i {} \;"